# C# RestSharp RestClient failed after 100 request to the same API

Tags: c#, for-loop, request, restsharp

I have a issue when i use RestSharp RestClient. I try to make multiple request inside a loop but it always failed after the 99th request.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Count : {i}");
    try
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("/endpoint/0016GMLCLT00000007456", Method.GET)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            JsonSerializer = new JsonDeserializer()
        };

        request.AddParameter("accepteEmail", "true");

        var response = RestClient.Execute<AuthenticateResponse>(request);

        Console.WriteLine($"API TEST : {response.Content}");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"API TEST : FAIL");
    }
}
```

I can see this on my terminal when i execute the code

```
Count : 97
API TEST : {"response":"YES","description":"you did it"}
Count : 98
API TEST : {"response":"YES","description":"you did it"}
Count : 99
API TEST :
Count : 100
API TEST :
Count : 101
API TEST :
```

Why it's working 99 times and after i have nothing??

EDIT : I have done the same code in JAVA and tried also 120 iterations of the request in POSTMAN and it's working. And it's also works with HTTP URL but not HTTPS after 100 times. And i add that to the code to see the problem

```
 Console.WriteLine($"API TEST : {response.ErrorMessage}");
```

And it tells me

```
 The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send
```

Comment: Appearantly it does not throw exception. Response returns no content. Must be sth with the API.

Comment: @SeckinCelik, i thought the same but i have tried the same in Java and it's working. the problem is not the API so.

Comment: Are you executing this locally? Or is it being run on a server somewhere?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith it is running on a server somewhere, not locally

Comment: Thanks @Siick, if you are running in a sandboxed environment such as an Azure App Service for example, you may be hitting socket limits perhaps? https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#per-sandbox-per-appper-site-numerical-limits I'd guess other services impose such limitations as well.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith No i am not running it in a sandboxed environment sauch as Azure. I run that code on visual Studio 2017 on my laptop

Comment: Cool, Do you own the API?

Perhaps you are hitting a web application firewall on the API, it's typical that an API has throttling built in, with your code in a tight loop it's likely you'd trip a a limit.

Maybe your test on Java and Postman was just lucky it passed?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith No it was not just luck, in JAVA it's working every time i try.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Do you own the API? Or is it a 3rd party? i.e. are you privy to the security policies?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith  i own the API

Comment: Good to know, that can make a big difference, it might be worthwhile you describing your server side environment in case anyone can spot a gotcha.

Comment: As a more general comment, the sorts of things to look for when doing http connections at scale would be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions from 'Execute' are not thrown but are available in the 'ErrorException' response property. And you need to check that this property is not null after executing the request. 
For your case you need to add something like this:

```
var response = RestClient.Execute<AuthenticateResponse>(request);

if (response.ErrorException == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"API TEST : {response.Content}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"API TEST : FAIL {response.ErrorException.Message}");
}
```

Comment: (Opinion) That sounds like a brilliant design.

Comment: I have done this and give an answer on the EDIT zone of my question. And it tells me

 The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send